# I am trying to achieve curved dashed lines using css

Tags: html, css

I am using background image and position but did not get desired results.

[image]

Comment: You have some code?

Comment: You can use leaderline librart here https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/

Comment: you're probably better off using SVGs instead of writing this in pure CSS